# What is the 'N' icon on rear LCD of a Nikon D7500?

Tags: camera-settings, display, rear-lcd, nikon-d7500

I have recently received my D7500 (upgrading from an original D70!) and I am perplexed by one icon on the rear screen that I can't seem to locate information about.

It is at the left side at the top of the rear screen (above the line) and looks like a small, white rectangle with a black oval interior and the letter `N` next to it.  I haven't been able to find it in the manual, but here is an out of focus picture (taken with my beloved Canon G15)

[image]

On the same level, and to the right of this icon is the `Hand` icon that indicates VR being switched on for the attached lens.  This makes me think that it may be a lens related icon, but as all of my other lenses are genuine Nikon, I get the same icon no matter what lens is connected.

Can anyone enlighten me as to what this `N` icon means?

Comment: A picture is worth almost all of the words in your question. =) Can you upload a picture of the icon you're describing?

Comment: @scottbb Make me get out my second camera why don't you!  But see the image.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are describing is the **Vignette Control Indicator**.

From page 203 of the [D7500 User Manual](http://download.nikonimglib.com/archive3/pOh2K00ajzME03jqjOD07oO8kL02/D7500UM_NT(En)02.pdf), the area pointed to by "27":

[image]

[image]

From page 255 of the manual,

> **Vignette control** (defaults to **Normal**)
>
> High, Normal, Low, Off
>
> Reduces the drop in brightness at the edges of photographs when using type G, E, and D lenses (PC lenses excluded). The effect is most noticeable at maximum aperture.

Comment: I have been through that damn manual twice already and with my camera in hand but I obviously missed it.  And at 356 pages of small print, it is no light read.

Comment: What? You don't find it engaging and page-turning?

Comment: Given the step up from my D70 I find it somewhat overwhelming!  On the other hand this camera does have a tad more features.

Comment: Follow up comment here.  Last night I re-read the manual section that your  answer comes from.  It is in the chapter called "Other Shooting Options". and all it does is point to the section of the manual that simply lists the menu options.  IMHO this is really poor documentation compared to the rest of the manual.  No explanation is given to why I would want to change it from the default.  And most of other options in this section are treated the same way.

Comment: Yeah manuals are frequently not really that helpful. It is kind of sad really. There are several authors that write books that might be worth considering. My personal favourite is Thom Hogan: http://www.dslrbodies.com/books/bythom-complete-guides-/ He does not have one for the D7500 yet. Frankly what I like about his work is he actually uses the cameras for a time before writing about them. It is slower but makes for better work - IMHO.

Comment: @PeterM I saw that too reading the D7500 manual. I think there's a raft of new features that Nikon has thrown in, and because they're not very widespread, they haven't flushed out the information about those features in the manuals. For instance, if shooting RAW, does Vignette Control matter? Is it applied only to in-camera generated JPEGs, or is it applied to the RAW data as well? Is it a meta tag / flag for Nikon's Capture NX to process RAW files? I wish Nikon would clarify, because I'd hate to do in-camera vignette control applied, forget, then do it again in LR with lens correction.

Comment: You questions both inform and worry me!  Anyway I just took 2 photos in RAW of the same blank wall.  One with Vignette Control turned off and one with it on Full.  Looking at the histogram on the back of the camera I can see a visible shift to the right for the full vignette control image.  However I am not 100% sure if the histogram is of the RAW image or of the JPG construct displayed on the LCD.

Comment: Just opened both RAW images in Affinity Photo and I can see histogram differences there.  So it look like it is a RAW modification.  That plus me having access to the menu item when the camera is configured to shoot RAW only.  Also the `Picture Control` menu items are also available in RAW mode and I had the understanding that they affected the RAW file